# How can I stop Chrome from slowing and freezing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I know Google Chrome 14 is a dev product, but I'm really wondering about my issues.
I do surf both German and English websites. And I guess my problem might be rather related to some extension!

In general my issues are:

- Chrome is loading slowly
- My laptop fan is running high all the time, and most of all:
- It's not loading or often freezing websites (while in the opening process of their tab) until I restart the browser!

It doesn't only happen with a few sites, but with a lot!
Sometimes it especially has problems with Google. Google+ is not working at all at times (but in the other browsers), Google Maps are not loading at all or totally improperly/unusable. And GMail isn't loading some times (rather rare) too. So somehow ironically Googles own products fail in Chrome!

I though, ok maybe it is Flash or Ads, but no, because I got "AdBlock" and "FlashControl" installed, what more can I do?

Now here is my whole extension list, maybe one is known to cause problems (I constantly check them and uninstall or deactivate any extension possible or replace it with a more frequently updated one! But it doesn't help! I already uninstalled stuff like AdSweep + XE (exchange rates), which I'd normally use, just to keep the extension count "low".)

Extensions: (33)

- RoboForm - Version: 7.4.1.0 (Entpackt)
- ActiveInbox for Gmail™? - Version: 4.0.2.20
- AdBlock - Version: 2.4.20
- Clip an Evernote - Version: 5.1.15.1534
- Diigo Bookmark, Archive, Highlight & Sticky-Note - Version: 1.6.4
- FlashControl - Version: 2.6.0
- History 2 - Version: 0.6.0
- Lazarus: Form Recovery - Version: 3.0.3.1
- Linkclump - Version: 2.0.14
- LiquidPlanner Extension for Chrome - Version: 1.0.1
- Mail Checker Plus+ for Google - Version: 1.0.1
- Proxy Switchy! - Version: 1.6.3
- Reload All Tabs - Version: 3.2.1
- Scroll To Top Button - Version: 6.1.1
- Session Buddy - Version: 2.1.2
- Shareaholic für Google Chrome - Version: 4.0.3
- Shoyu RSS/Atom Feed Preview - Version: 2.0.3.10
- Slinky G+ - Version: 0.1.1.3
- Speed Dial - Version: 2.1
- Stop Autoplay for YouTube. - Version: 0.11.5.24
- WiseStamp - Email Signatures for GMail, Google Apps and more - Version: 2.6.0.0
- word highlight - Version: 1.2.0
- Xmarks Bookmark Sync - Version: 1.0.16

Deactivated extensions:

- +1 Button - Plus One Button - Version: 0.2.4 (Deaktiviert)
- 1-Click Web Proxy - Version: 1.8.83 (Deaktiviert)
- bit.ly | a simple URL shortener - Version: 1.2.1.12 (Deaktiviert)
- Chrome Nanny - Version: 0.989 (Deaktiviert)
- ChromeItLater - Version: 0.3.1 (Deaktiviert)
- Grooveshark Non-Stop - Version: 1.1 (Deaktiviert)
- JDownloader Integration for Google Chrome™ - Version: 1.2.3 (Deaktiviert)
- Microformats for Google Chrome - Version: 0.4.5 (Deaktiviert)
- Tab Menu - Version: 7 (Deaktiviert)
- Tampermonkey - Version: 2.0.2395 (Deaktiviert)

Comment: Just disable everything and see if it works. If yes, then go through the list. If its still slow, re-install.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Have you tried clearing your Cache or History? Have you tried disabling Flash completely?
(These are the things I usually end up doing on my dinky 4-year-old bottom of the line computer. They may or may not help yours.)

Comment: I clear cache + history constantly. How does "FlashControl" not disable Flash completely? I got 8 GB of RAM. Disabling all at once is not possible in Chrome, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Chrome loads slowly because when it starts up, it has to load, initilalize, and run each and every one of those extensions and plugins (which you have not listed).
2. Your laptop fan runs all the time because Chrome is putting so much of a load on your CPU, that it heats up, requiring your fan to cool it down. Open the Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Escape) to view the CPU usage graph in the notification area as below.
3. 1. Pages frequently “freeze” because today’s web pages are not just a tiny, static piece of text, but rather large, dynamic, multi-media monsters. They use up a lot more processing power for all that Flash, JavaScript, videos, interactivity, etc.
   2. On top of the page-related CPU load, you’ve also got a whole bunch of active extensions which impose their own performance hit. A lot of those extensions are active and do processing for *every* web page, while others only do so for certain web pages, but even then, they still have to do *some* processing to determine whether the current page is one of their targets or not. All this processing adds up and puts a heck of load on the CPU.

Check what plugins you have installed and enabled (`chrome://plugins`).

Next, disable everything you don’t absolutely need on a regular basis. Even if there is a plugin or extension that you think you need normally, consider when the last time you actually used it was. Did you use it today? Did you use it yesterday? If not, disable it. It is simple enough to enable extensions and plugins when you actually need them, so there’s no reason to burden your system with unnecessary processing the rest of the time (you’ll also find that your system runs cooler and quieter that way).

[image: Task manager notification area graph]

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using a developer version which might just be broken, check out the next update.
2. Disable all extensions. Then go troubleshoot which extension that you enable causes the problem.
3. Reset the browser settings and/or create a new user profile to get rid of configuration issues.
4. Switch back to a non developer build, you can't expect *dev* to just work and you might not need it.

Comment: I usually update on the most recent version. The problem actually persists since a long time, at least as far as I can remember. ...how does one actually create a (new) "user profile" in Chrome? O.o As far as I know it is synced to the cloud and connected to my usual Google account? And there are not so many settings in Chrome, at least I didn't fumble around with them.

Comment: [See this article](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059).